# Clarify lttng behaviour and performance: printing to console?

Tags: lttng

I'm looking for up to date info on LTTng, specifically around its performance overhead compared to printk.

[This discussion](https://lists.lttng.org/pipermail/lttng-dev/2010-June/013920.html) from 2010 indicates that one of the advantages of lttng over printk is that it doesn't use up resources pretty-printing to the console. However, when I quickly followed the [docs simple example](https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-tracing-the-linux-kernel) I got a terminal output as well as the binary. Not as pretty as printk's, but it still is outputting to console. So I just wanted to clarify:

(1) Back in 2010, did LTTng not output to the terminal at all?

(2) Does the difference in formatting (printk with nice colours etc. vs LTTng's default text splurge) mean LTTng still has a performance advantage when comparing outputs?

Bonus question: does anyone have any recent LTTng benchmarking resources? The most recent I could find was [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/526a/d0efab298489164587fa1ba3ba838bd38ee3.pdf) from 2006.